# IMAP: how to find all drafts

Tags: php, imap

How i can retrieve all messages from inbox using php imap_xxxx() functions marked as draft?

RFC 2060 says that imap supports DRAFT keyword, but its not working in php (unknown keyword).

Is there any other way to get all drafts?

Answer (score 0):

All of my mail clients save draft messages in a folder called "Drafts", rather than in the Inbox.  I'm not sure whether the `\Draft` flag is also used.